# JQuery postJson adds a "0" when passing a variables value

Tags: jquery, json, api, breeze, pass-by-reference

here my first question on stackoverflow:

I have a little problem: when passing a value from a html input field to a JQuery Json post i get a 0 in front of the text from the input.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
This is the post:

```
  $( "#submit-project" ).click(function( event ) {
      alert( "submitting project" );
      var description_text = descr.value;
      var projectName = projectN.value;
      $.postJSON({
        url: 'https://api.breeze.pm/projects.json?api_token= ...',
        data: {
```

> "name": +''+projectName+'',
>
> "description": +''+description_text+'',

```
        "budget_amount": "0",
        "budget_hours": "0",
        "hourly_rate": "0",
        "currency_symbol": "€",
        "invitees": ["email"]
      },
      success: function(json) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(json));
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(err.responseText);
        // TODO stimmt das so?
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

and this is where the input comes from:

```
<input type="text" id="descr" name="project-description" >
```

...If I enter the value manually I doenst add thew 0...

The result:

```
    {"id":41785,"name":"0sddf","description":"0sdfff","budget_amount":"0.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0 appears in front of the input text due to the leading + that you've defined the name and description variables with , instead change them to :

```
"name": ''+projectName+'', //TODO brackets
"description": ''+description_text+'', // TODO brackets
```

The leading 0 should now have been removed.

https://jsfiddle.net/f10rby1e/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

You pass `+''+projectName+''` as a value in your data, notice the plus sign that is whats causing the 0. the plus sign operates on the empty string converting it to a number (0) and then concatenated to project name. Remove the `+''+` from there and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply :-)